# Is there any way to pass value to variable and sum?

Tags: php, mysql

for eg: I had 3 values in table item:

```
car <br>
bike<br>
cycle<br>
```

In product page when clicking on any product it will pass value to next page and store it as variable, I want to find the sum of item that passed from another page

the code is here.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $qry=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM addingre WHERE id=$id", $con);
        if(!$qry){
            die("Query Failed: ". mysql_error());
        }

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
            $ttt= "<h2>".$row['ingredients']."</h2>";
        }
    }
?>
<?php
    echo "$ttt";
?>

<?php
    $query_check_credentials = "SELECT product, SUM(quantity) AS total_amount FROM ingredients WHERE item = '$ttt' GROUP BY product";

    $res = mysql_query($query_check_credentials);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        echo $row['total_amount'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: This question seems very unclear.  Please edit the question fully explaining the goal, what you've tried, and where exactly it is going wrong.

Comment: yes ..like said by mickmackusa   please explian better your question

Comment: In case English isn't your mother tongue, here's a guess: Do you want to do a "grand total' of the sums in addition to the individual product sums?  If so, you can just use php in your while loop `$total+=$row['total_amount'];`

Comment: english isn't my mother tongue, for me it is very hard to explain @mickmackusa

Comment: edited question,please look now

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not following.  Can you explain exactly where your code breaks/fails?  Is `$row['total_amount']` giving a result? the correct result?  Is the query returning any rows in the result set? or is there an error?  Please give more information.

Comment: when i put on the line where item =' bike ' it shows correct answer, but when i try where item = '$ttt' it didnt show any thing, blank page, no errors @mickmackusa

Comment: It looks like you aren't doing any error detection on your query.  I see that you are wrapping $ttt in <h2></h2> tags.  When you echo $ttt is will format the text and the tag syntax will disappear.  As for the query, if you are seaching for 'bike', but feeding '<h2>bike</h2' into the query, you will receive no rows in the result set.

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not add `<h2></h2>` when first declaring the `$ttt` variable.

Leave it bare.   e.g. 'bike'

Only add the tags when echoing.  e.g. `echo "<h2>$ttt</h2>";`

This will allow you to reuse $ttt in the query.